Remove string with special characters
Within a bash script, I need to have a line that will look for this specific string (see below) including the special characters and remove them.  Any ideas please?
 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>


What are the special characters?

Assuming you want all occurrences of the " | CHANGED | rc=0 >>" string to be removed from the contents of a file, with perl:
perl -i -pe 's/\Q | CHANGED | rc=0 >>\E//g' file

With some sed implementations including GNU sed which have copied perl's -i option, you can also do:
sed -i 's/ | CHANGED | rc=0 >>//g' your-file

space, |, > (and in some contexts =) are only special to the shell when unquoted.
| is special in perl regular expressions or extended regular expressions (as with sed -E), but not in basic regular expressions (as with sed without -E/-r/-P/-A...).
To escape a character so it loses its special meaning in a regular expression, you prefix it with \, but you don't want to do that for characters that do not have a special meaning as doing so could actually give them a special meaning. For instance | and > are not special in BREs, but \| and \> are special for some BRE engines including the one used by GNU sed. Using a bracket expression is another way to have a character take literally ([|] matches a literal | in all of BRE, ERE, perl RE¹).
In perl, with \Q...\E everything between the \Q and \E is taken literally, so you don't have to worry about characters that would happen to otherwise be regex operators.

¹ You can't use that for ^ though, and for \, you'd want to use [\\], [\] being non-portable; you'll have troubles with the newline character as well.

You didn't give context, but when you say remove the specific string I assume you mean remove the specific substring from another string, in which case you can simply replace it with an empty string like so:
inputstr="TEST | CHANGED | rc=0 >>TEST";
emptystr="";
echo "${inputstr/ | CHANGED | rc=0 >>/"$emptystr"}";

Such a result will be "TESTTEST."
